# Azure Function App log streaming: only works intermittently

Tags: azure-functions, azureportal, azure-durable-functions

I have a Durable Function that I'm trying to view streaming logs for in the Azure Portal, but for some reason I can only seem to view logs perhaps one in every 10 or 20 times I try connecting to the log streaming service.  When it doesn't work, it looks as if it connects but nothing is shown on screen besides the basic:

```
Connecting...
2019-09-10T05:51:31  Welcome, you are now connected to log-streaming service. The default timeout is 2 hours. Change the timeout with the App Setting SCM_LOGSTREAM_TIMEOUT (in seconds).
2019-09-10T05:52:32  No new trace in the past 1 min(s).
2019-09-10T05:53:32  No new trace in the past 2 min(s).
(... etc)
```

I know the function is working because it will process items from the queue just fine, and I can keep trying to reconnect to the service and eventually it reconnects "properly" and I see the logs.  I'm not sure if it's just me, but it seems to have more luck connecting just after the function app has been restarted.

Some background:

- My durable function app (using Functions 2.0) has about 20 functions including the orchestrators, sub-orchestrations and activity functions.  Hmmm... 20 functions, and a 1-in-20 chance of connecting - coincidence?  Perhaps each *function* has its own log stream, and connecting to the function app stream will randomly pick a function until I get the right one?  But the thing is that most of my functions log stuff, and I only ever see all logs or (most of the time) nothing.
- The logs are just using standard Functions logging, nothing special.  The only other thing I'm using regarding logging is `Services.AddApplicationInsightsTelemetry()`.

What could be causing the log stream to only connect sometimes?

Comment: Suppose this is the  streaming timeout,doesn't always show the logs. you could go to the kudu site check the log file.Go to  https://[your-function-app].scm.azurewebsites.net/, Debug console > CMD,go into `D:\home\LogFiles\Application\Functions\Host\`  or  `D:\home\LogFiles\Application\Functions\Function\function-name\`.

Answer (score 1):

You may refer to this tutorial:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-dotnet-dependency-injection#logging-services

[image]

Comment: Thanks, I think you are suggesting to remove AddApplicationInsightsTelemetry - I wish that was it, I've tried removing it and redeploying and it hasn't fixed the problem.  But thanks for the heads up on that - I had seen it before but forgot about it.

Comment: Hey, any update on this ? Encountering similar issue. Just checking the kudu is not sufficient for me.

Comment: Same issue here with a TypeScript function. Even the hosted version seems to be buggy (one year later)